# Memory Leak Problem with MKMapViewDelegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

The code I have is:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Pin"];

if(pinView == nil)
{
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"];
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    [pinView setCanShowCallout:YES];

    if([[(MapPin *)annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Starting Location"])
    {
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }

}

return pinView;
```

The problem of course is that I have to return pinView, which I allocate and need to release at some point. However, once I return pinView, I cannot release it because the method call terminates. How do I get around this? Thanks!

Comment: autorelease is one way to go about it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: Unrelated to your question (to which yAak has the answer): The `pinView.annotation = annotation;` line should be moved to an else part (need to set annotation if pinView != nil) since if pinView == nil, the annotation is set when you alloc+init it.

Comment: Also: the checking of the title and the setting of the pinColor and accessory view should be done outside the main `if` right before the return pinView so the view properties are updated in case it is being re-used from another annotation.

Comment: @yAak: you could post this as a real answer, IMO.

Comment: @yAak, please put your response as the answer so I can accept it. I was putting autorelease in the wrong place (in the first line, rather than where it's allocated), which was why I was getting the "analyze" tool to complain. When I removed it, I got a "potential memory leak" warning. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Done! Sorry, I was reluctant to post something so brief as an answer, and unintentional misuse of autorelease can cause its own problems... so I put more emphasis on the documentation link. =)

Comment: That's alright! Thanks! Also, @AnnaKarenina, thanks for those pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `autorelease` is a way to solve issues like this~  Although, be aware of what autorelease pool your object is being placed into to ensure proper lifespan. =)

Very valuable documentation link for anyone figuring this stuff out: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html